# How to make Class to be constant when we hover a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed industry page for website but the issue when we hover that class should be constant and image and border should be displayed when we remove the cursor the resest to the previous images.and border shoud not display below i have shared the code and script please help me anyone.

Here am sharing the demo please check it
   http://floretmedia.net/temp/tgs/industries.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBKtg.jpg)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".food").hover(function(){
       $("#food").show();
       $("#fmcg").hide();
       $("#retail").hide();
     });
     $(".fmcg").hover(function(){
        $("#food").hide();
        $("#fmcg").show();
        $("#retail").hide();
     });
      $(".retail").hover(function(){
         $("#food").hide();
         $("#fmcg").hide();
         $("#retail").show();
      });
       $(".indus-icn-lst").hover(function(){
       $(this).find(".indus-category");
       $(this).toggleClass("indusactive");
      });
 });
```

```css
.indus-list{border-right:1px solid #FFC300;}
.indus h2{
  font-size: 46px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}
.indus-icn-lst{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
.food{background: url(../images/icon-spirite.png)-130px -181px;}
.indusactive.food {background: url(../images/icon-spirite.png)-25px -181px;}
.fmcg{background: url(../images/icon-spirite.png)-300px -181px;}
.indusactive.fmcg{background: url(../images/icon-spirite.png)-225px -181px;}
.retail{background: url(../images/icon-spirite.png)-300px -181px;}
.electronic{background: url(../images/icon-spirite.png)-300px -181px;}
.black-bg{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#0000009c;
  padding: 80px 40px;
}
.indusactive:after{
  right: -150px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FDC300;
}
.indus-category{display: none}
.indusactive{display: block;}
.indusactive:after{
  right: -150px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FDC300;
}
```

```html
<section class="industries cf">
  <div class="wd-20 text-center pt-65 indus-list">
    <h4 class="mb-35">INDUSTRIES</h4>
    <div class="indus-icon text-center">
       <div class="indus-icn-lst food">
       </div>  <!-- indus-item -->
        <div class="indus-icn-lst fmcg">
       </div>  <!-- indus-item -->
       <div class="indus-icn-lst retail">
       </div>  <!-- indus-item -->
       <div class="indus-icn-lst electronic">
       </div>  <!-- indus-item -->
    </div> <!-- indus-icon -->
  </div><!-- indus-list -->
  <div id="food" class="indus">
     <div class="wd-40 px-65 indus-txt">
        <div class="beverage cf">
           <div class="indus-img-dlt mb-4">
             <img src="images/icons/food.png" alt="food"/>
           </div><!-- indus-img-dlt -->
            <h2>Food &  Beverage</h2>
            <div class="mt-2 cf">
              <p class="cb">Fresh , On Time Every time</p>
               <p>Believe in Time Global Shipping  when you need a trust worthy logistic and supply chain vendor to help plan the daily operations . We help our food and beverage clients to solve the supply and delivery challenges with their daily supplies . From product pick up through the delivery, We provide :</p>
              <ul class="d-block mb-3">
                <li>A temperature controlled supply chain (uninterrupted cold chain for both fleet and warehousing)</li>
                <li>Flexible vendor pickups and just-in-time delivery</li>
                <li>Equipment tracking</li>
                <li>Understanding of store and vendor requirements</li>
                <li>Delivery coordination between vendors and stores</li>
             </ul>
              <p>Our approach is simple. Our industry knowledge allow us to engineer distribution networks that exceed our customers' expectations. By reducing miles and time, you'll get the benefit of delivering a fresher product.</p>
              <p>When you need to deliver the freshest food and beverage products daily, partner with the experts who know your business as well as you do.</p>
          </div><!-- mt-2 -->
        </div> <!-- beverage -->
     </div><!-- indus-txt -->
     <div class="wd-40 indus-dlt-img">
       <div class="beverage-img">
          <figure>
            <img src="images/industries/fmcg.jpg" alt="food and beverage"/>
         </figure>
      </div><!-- beverage-img -->
      <div class="black-bg">
      </div>
     </div><!-- indus-dlt-img -->
  </div><!-- indus -->
  <div class="indus indus-category" id="fmcg">
     <div class="wd-40 px-65 indus-txt">
        <div  class="beverage cf">
           <div class="indus-img-dlt mb-4">
              <img src="images/icons/fmcg.png" alt="Fmcg"/>
           </div><!-- indus-img-dlt -->
            <h2>FMCG</h2>
            <div class="mt-2 cf">
              <p class="cb">Fresh , On Time Every time</p>
               <p>Believe in Time Global Shipping  when you need a trust worthy logistic and supply chain vendor to help plan the daily operations . We help our food and beverage clients to solve the supply and delivery challenges with their daily supplies . From product pick up through the delivery, We provide :</p>
              <ul class="d-block mb-3">
                <li>A temperature controlled supply chain (uninterrupted cold chain for both fleet and warehousing)</li>
                <li>Flexible vendor pickups and just-in-time delivery</li>
                <li>Equipment tracking</li>
                <li>Understanding of store and vendor requirements</li>
                <li>Delivery coordination between vendors and stores</li>
             </ul>
              <p>Our approach is simple. Our industry knowledge allow us to engineer distribution networks that exceed our customers' expectations. By reducing miles and time, you'll get the benefit of delivering a fresher product.</p>
              <p>When you need to deliver the freshest food and beverage products daily, partner with the experts who know your business as well as you do.</p>
          </div><!-- mt-2 -->
        </div> <!-- beverage -->
     </div><!-- indus-txt -->
     <div class="wd-40 indus-dlt-img">
       <div class="fmcg-img">
          <figure>
            <img src="images/industries/retail.jpg" alt="Retail"/>
         </figure>
      </div><!-- fmcg-img -->
      <div class="black-bg">
      </div>
     </div><!-- indus-dlt-img -->
  </div><!-- indus -->  
  <div class="indus indus-category" id="retail">
     <div class="wd-40 px-65 indus-txt">
        <div class="beverage cf">
           <div class="indus-img-dlt mb-4">
              <img src="images/icons/retail.png" alt="retail"/> 
           </div><!-- indus-img-dlt -->
            <h2>RETAIL</h2>
            <div class="mt-2 cf">
              <p class="cb">We have experience in serving the delivery and retail supply chain management needs of stores of all sizes and configurations. From big box to convenience.</p>
               <p>Time Global shipping's retail logistic services can be of your benefit in ways of reducing costs. Helping you serve your customers better and improving inventory management.</p>
              <p>We engineer distribution networks that work for retail. Efficient routes and resources utilization tailored to seasonal ups and downs.</p>
              <p>Our well-trained and courteous drivers provide excellent customer service to stores and use the most-advanced technology available to monitor, track, and trace products.</p>
          </div><!-- mt-2 -->
        </div> <!-- beverage -->
     </div><!-- indus-txt -->
     <div class="wd-40 indus-dlt-img">
       <div class="retail-img">
          <figure>
            <img src="images/industries/food.jpg" alt="food and beverage"/>
         </figure>
      </div><!-- fmcg-img -->
      <div class="black-bg">
      </div>
     </div><!-- indus-dlt-img -->
  </div><!-- indus -->
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific?! which is the class you are referring to?
what is the expected output? can you please add screenshots of the expected output?

Comment: I have attatched the expected output screen shot.

Comment: Hi Sir,  Currently when i hover  the side image(food or fmcg)   the hovered image and right border will display but when  move the cursor out the side image border and hovered it not displaying.  Expected output is when we hover fmcg right content is changing and the content is constant like that when i hover fmcg icon the left border and black color icon should be constant

Comment: Please anyone help me

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and share it across ? I'm unable to recreate the design with the current code.

Comment: I have added Code in Jsfiddle  but scrpit in not working sir

Comment: Please check it https://jsfiddle.net/anitha_nagadasari/mw1ot32s/14/

Comment: please anyone help me

Comment: The jsfiddle you have provided is not working. the borders you have mention in the question is not seen.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can replace this part of your code:

```
$(".indus-icn-lst").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".indus-category");
    $(this).toggleClass("indusactive");
});
```

With this code:

```
$(".indus-icn-lst").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('indusactive')
    $(this).find(".indus-category");
    $(this).addClass("indusactive");
 });
```

This sets the class on hover and keeps it, but removes it when you hover another category